# Plotting cross validation of ridge regression's MSE

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regression, glmnet

first of all, I have to apologize for my poor English. Second, the objective of this post is that I want to reproduce the plot of the ridge regression's MSE with ggplot2 instead of the function `plot` which is included in R.

The object of `cv.out` is defined by the next expression:
`cv.out <- cv.glmnet(x_var[train,], y_var[train], alpha = 0)`. And when I print that object these are the elements of `cv.out`

|  | Lambda | Measure | SE | Nonzero |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| min | 439.8 | 32554969 | 1044541 | 5 |
| lse | 1343.1 | 33586547 | 1068662 | 5 |

This is the plot with `plot(cv.out)`:

[image: Image of the plot]

The thing what I want to do the same plot but more elaborated with `ggplot` and I don't know which aesthetics put in the function. These are the elements of cv.out when I call the object like this: `cv.out$` :

- lambda
- cmv
- cvsd
- cvup
- cvlo
- nzero
- call
- name
- lambda.min
- lambda.lse

Finally, thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using example dataset:

```
X = as.matrix(mtcars[,-1])
y = as.matrix(mtcars[,1])
cv.out = cv.glmnet(X,y,alpha=0)
plot(cv.out)
```

[image]

You just need to pull out the values and put into a data.frame, and plot using `geom_point()` and `geom_errorbar()` :

```
df = with(cv.out,
     data.frame(lambda = lambda,MSE = cvm,MSEhi=cvup,MSElow=cvlo))

ggplot(df,aes(x=lambda,y=MSE)) + 
geom_point(col="#f05454") + 
scale_x_log10("log(lambda)") + 
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = MSElow,ymax=MSEhi),col="#30475e") + 
geom_vline(xintercept=c(cv.out$lambda.1se,cv.out$lambda.min),
linetype="dashed")+
theme_bw()
```

[image]