# MSE of the validation (and test) sets from repeated k-Fold on Ridge regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, cross-validation, mse

TLDR Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65346637/) problem but how can we do it using `sklearn`? I'm okay if only the mean over the CVs I did for each `lambda` or `alpha` are shown in the plots.

---

Hi all, if I understand correctly, we need to cross-validate on the training set to select the `alpha` (as in `sklearn`) for the ridge regression. In particular, I want to perform a 5-fold CV repeated 5 times (so 25 CVs) on the training set.

What I *want* to do is for each `alpha` from the `alphas`:

```py
from numpy import logspace as logs
alphas = logs(-3, 3, 71) # from 10^{-3}, 10^{-2.9}, ..., to 10^3
```

I get the MSEs on the 25 (different?) validation sets, and the MSE on the test set after I finish all the CVs for each training set, then take the average out of the 25 MSEs for plotting or reporting.

The **issue** is I'm not sure how to do so. Is this the correct code to retrieve the 25 MSEs from the validation sets which we usually couldn't observe?

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV, Ridge
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score as CVS

# 5 fold now repeated all 5 times
cvs = RKF(n_splits=5, n_repeats=5, random_state=42)

# each alpha input as al
# the whole data set is generated with different RNG each time
# if you like you may take any existing data sets to explain whether I did wrong
# for each whole data set, the training set is split using the same random state
CVS(Ridge(alpha=al, random_state=42), X_train, Y_train, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv=cvs)
```

If no, should I use `cross_validate` or even `RidgeCV` to get the MSEs I want?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to use GridSearchCV, using an example where we have 10 values of alpha:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, RepeatedKFold
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV,Ridge
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from numpy import logspace as logs
from sklearn import datasets

alphas = logs(-3, 3, 71) 

diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data[:300]
y = diabetes.target[:300]

X_val = diabetes.data[300:]
y_val = diabetes.target[300:]
```

We define the repeated cross validation, and the alphas to fit over:

```
cvs = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=5, n_repeats=5, random_state=42)
parameters = {'alpha':alphas}

clf = GridSearchCV(Ridge(), parameters,cv=cvs)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

So the means of the scores will be stored under `clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score']` and you also have the individual results under the dictionary. To plot, you can simply do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(np.arange(len(alphas)), height =clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score'],
       yerr=clf.cv_results_['std_test_score'], alpha=0.5,
       error_kw=dict(ecolor='gray', lw=1, capsize=5, capthick=2))

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(alphas)))
ax.set_xticklabels(np.round(alphas,3))
```

[image]

This shows the mean and standard error of the score over 10 values of alpha.

You can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948879/using-explicit-predefined-validation-set-for-grid-search-with-sklearn) on how to get the scores for a pre-defined validation set.